# Is it possible to disable Sass in Rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, ruby, sass, nexus

I work in a completely air-gapped environment in which I would love to use Ruby on Rails. I have the ability to cache dependencies for offline use in Nexus. The problem I'm having is that after I've cached all my dependencies for Rails 6 (including the NodeJS ones), `node-sass` is unable to install because it attempts to download a file from GitHub.

I'm completely fine without using a CSS pre-processor, and would much rather deal with vanilla CSS than deal with this dependency headache. Is it possible to disable just Sass support when creating a new Rails app? I'm able to use `--skip-javascript` to disable all javascript support, but since all the other dependencies are able to be installed, it would be a shame to have to disable them just because `node-sass` can't be installed offline. Is there an option like that for Sass?

I'm aware I could manually copy the `.node` file from the GitHub release page, however, I'm trying to make this process as minimalistic and automatable as possible.

I'm working with Fedora Linux if that's relevant.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?  I'm investigating the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I think `--skip-sprockets` option will disable Sass. You can also disable webpacker using `--skip-javascript`.

You may try below command.

```
rails new green-forest -S -J
```